# strptime error with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am creating a simple validation inside of my model that checks to see if a date (`to_date`) is before the current date.

The format the user submits the `to_date` in is `%m/%d/%Y` or for example, `03/15/2016`.

My issue, is rails is throwing me an `invalid date` error, although I have triple checked that the date is in the correct format.

Here is my validation:

```
validate  :date_not_before_now

def date_not_before_now
  if Date.strptime(self.to_date, '%m/%d/%Y').strftime("%Y-%m-%d") < Time.now.localtime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
  errors.add(:dates, "should not be in the past.")
end
```

end

Any help figuring out why this isn't working would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try this when validating date

```
validates :date_field, presence: true, date: {on_or_before: :today}

def today
  Date.today
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but on_or_before won't work in my case, since the `to_date` is a string -- not a datetime.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
validate  :date_not_before_now

def date_not_before_now
  if ( Date.strptime(self.to_date, '%m/%d/%Y') < Time.now.localtime.to_date)
    errors.add(:dates, "should not be in the past.")
  end
end
```

Tried in console and worked see the following e.g.

```
Date.strptime("03/15/2016", '%m/%d/%Y') < Time.now.localtime.to_date
## Output
=> true
```